# Publish and subscribe events in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Is it possible to publish and subscribe to events(like in ionic) for Component communication. The two components I have there are no related (there are not parent and child).
One component is a header that has a button Publish , and the other component is a form. What i want is to send an event from the clicked button to the form for validation purpose that says for example the field body cant be empty something like that.

EDIT:
I am using router flux. The component i have the form is NewPost and the one with the Button publish is ButtonsNewPost. Are this components parent and child? They can comunicate somehow?

```
        <Scene
          key="newPost"
          component={NewPost}
          hideNavBar={false}
          renderRightButton={<ButtonsNewPost/>}
          navBarButtonColor='#fff'
        >
```

SOLUTION:

newPost.js

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    let validationMessage;
    if(newProps.validationBody) {
        validationMessage = 'El campo descripción es requerido';
        this.showToastValidation(validationMessage);

        //without the next line the validation toast only appear once
        this.props.validation_body(false); 
    } 

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
    validationBody: state.validationBody
   }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        validation_body: (validationBody) => 
               dispatch(validation_body(validationBody))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewPost)
```

reducers/validationBody.js

```
export default (state = false, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'validation_body':
            return action.payload
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import validationBody from './validationBody';

export default combineReducers({
    validationBody: validationBody
})
```

actions/index.js

```
export const validation_body = (validationBody) => {
    return {
        type: 'validation_body',
        payload: validationBody
    }
}
```

buttonsNewPost.js

```
if (!window.description) {
   this.props.validation_body(true);
   return;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        validation_body: (validationBody) => 
         dispatch(validation_body(validationBody)),
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonsNewPost)
```

Comment: you should try use redux, or flux

Comment: Yes i solve it with redux. If anyone wants the code, just ask for it.

Comment: Better add the solution, and whoever needs it (i guess a lot of people) will be able to read it immediately.

Comment: @angelos_lex Done

Answer (score 5):

You can use the *react-native-event-listeners* library:

https://github.com/meinto/react-native-event-listeners

Usage is similar to Ionic events:

```
import { EventRegister } from 'react-native-event-listeners'

/*
 * RECEIVER COMPONENT
 */
class Receiver extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data: 'no data',
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.listener = EventRegister.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', (data) => {
            this.setState({
                data,
            })
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        EventRegister.removeEventListener(this.listener)
    }

    render() {
        return <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>
    }
}

/*
 * SENDER COMPONENT
 */
const Sender = (props) => (
    <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => {
            EventRegister.emit('myCustomEvent', 'it works!!!')
        })
    ><Text>Send Event</Text></TouchableHighlight>
)
```